# How to pass enum parameter to angular directive

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to pass enum as parameter to angular 6 directive, but it recognizes as a string

```js
export enum MyEnum {
    SomeValue = 1
}
```

directive code:

```
import { MyEnum } from '/path/';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appMyDir]'
})

export class MyDirDirective {
    constructor() { }

    private _role: MyEnum;

    @Input()
    public set role(val: MyEnum) {
        this._role = val;   // string
    }
```

usage of directive:

```
<button appMyDir role=MyEnum.SomeValue >Button</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only bind to properties of the component class. Set the enum to one of the  class properties and bind it to the directive.

```
import { MyEnum } from '/path/';

@Component({
   template: `
   <button appMyDir [role]="myEnum.SomeValue">Button</button>
   `
})

export class AppComponent {
  myEnum = MyEnum;
}
```

Comment: In your example the template is for the one enum value? What if I have multiple enum values?

Comment: You can set the role to any value you want. `[role]="myEnum.FirstValue"`  `[role]="myEnum.SecondValue"` and so on.

Comment: now I got following error:
```Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'role' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.```

Comment: Can't you explain how to bind component to directive?

Comment: Hello, I am getting the error that the property 'SomeValue' does not exist on typeof 'MyEnum'